# Are there libraries or existing methods to get a webpage's layout from the html and css?

Tags: layout, html

From the html and css files of a webpage, is there a way to write a program that can guess how the page might be visually structured?

Comment: it's called a "web browser", or an html rendering agent.

Comment: @MarcB I was thinking about somehow extracting the widest visual block of text content (as opposed to sidebars and navbars, footers, etc), preferrably in python. Navigating the dom is not very efficient as most sites have different markup.

Comment: then you'll have to render the page somehow. a 10 megabyte block of text might only occupy a few pixels ons creen because its font size is microscopic... unless you want to try and parse every potential oddball/extreme case like that, you'd be better off just rendering the page and using dom operations to extract calculated sizes and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

can try saving to website by right click and save webpage or save as, then open up in a program like dreamweaver.